# Ubuntu 17.10, change wm

Tags: 17.10, window-manager

Now that Ubuntu 17.10 uses Gnome, how can we easly change the window manager to use after login in?
With unity we could easly change the wm in the login area, what about now?

Comment: Do you mean `sudo apt install gdm` or `sudo apt install lightdm` ?

Comment: 17.10 uses gdm by default, http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-login-screen-preview

Answer (score 0):

You can still change the WM's in the login area, but you need to have them installed and configured properly in order for them to show up.

E.g., if you run `sudo apt install xfce4` and then log out, you will see the familiar "gear" widget to switch between "Ubuntu on Xorg" and XFCE.

> [ However, switching to XFCE doesn't actually work...  So I'm changing this answer to "community wiki" in case anyone can supply more details. ]

If you've installed some other window manager that doesn't do all of the configuration steps automatically you may need to create a new "desktop" entry in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Instructions for Ratpoison are [here](http://letsmaketech.com/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=16), for example, but it would be similar in other cases.

So this answer is relatively self-contained, I'll copy the key bits here. Run a command like this: `sudo nano /usr/share/xsessions/ratpoison.desktop` and add the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ratpoison
Comment=This session logs you into Ratpoison
Exec=/usr/bin/ratpoison
TryExec=/usr/bin/ratpoison
Icon=
Type=Application
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=ratpoison-session
```

I also installed Lubuntu via `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`, maybe this makes a difference.

> [ Booting to Ratpoison now works for me, yay! ]